# Implementing half stars in ionic

Tags: css, angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

So basically, i have a ionic mobile application that has a rating module. but, I'm having a hard time as to how to implement half stars when i get an average that is not a whole number. so what i did i round it off. and display the ionic icon star. these are my codes,

```
     <span *ngIf="item.rating" class="review">     
      {{item.rating}}
      <ion-icon name="star" *ngIf="Round(item.rating) > 0"></ion-icon>
      <ion-icon name="star" *ngIf="Round(item.rating) > 1"></ion-icon>
      <ion-icon name="star" *ngIf="Round(item.rating) > 2"></ion-icon>
      <ion-icon name="star" *ngIf="Round(item.rating) > 3"></ion-icon>
      <ion-icon name="star" *ngIf="Round(item.rating) > 4"></ion-icon>
    </span>
```

i wanted to get rid of the round off and display half stars how do i do it?

Comment: is it possible to half the icon star?

Answer (score 1):

Please look at this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic2-rating

Installation:

`npm install --save ionic2-rating`

Usage:

```
<rating
 [(ngModel)]="0.5"
 readOnly="true"
 max="5"
 emptyStarIconName="star-outline"
 halfStarIconName="star-half"
 starIconName="star"
 nullable="false">
</rating>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have some time use this library 
https://github.com/fraserxu/ionic-rating

or else you may use bootstrap.
Implementing the technique will increase code complexity and not considered as good practice.

Comment: can you help me how to use bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic2-rating

```
npm install --save ionic2-rating
```

work for me too to include half rating as well.
CSS customisation is there too.